# Android studio opening but now showing the program on windows

Tags: android-studio

When i try to open android studio it "opens" (i can see the logo on the taskbar of Windows), but it doesnt show the program! when i click the logo on the taskbar nothing happens, if i put the mouse on top of the logo i can see a white window in the previsualization. It was working fine yesterday i dont know what happened and to solve it, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your device. If it's done already and nothing changes then start Android Studio and end it using the task manager, then open it again. If both of these fail to solve the issue then do this:

1. Browse and find the project that is opened in the Android Studio. Cut the project and move it to another directory. ( So that Android Studio can't open it anymore with previous settings)
2. Then launch the Android Studio.

Let me know the update.

Comment: i solved it, i answer my own question with the solution that worked for me :) thanks!

Comment: Goog to know. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it erasing the folder "options" in the path

> c:/ users / "myuser" /  AppData (hidden) / Roaming /Google /
> AndroidStudioX.X / options

Then restarting the app (the app starts in default options). Hope it can be helpful to others :)